# karma: chrome browser idle, no test executes

Tags: node.js, windows, google-chrome, angular5, karma-jasmine

I am facing a similar problem. I am testing a sample Angular(1.6.3)app  When i run karma start or npm test, it runs the karma and shows no result in command prompt or in browser. I am able to see jasmine result on clicking DEBUG button in browser. Problem is that app is not displayed in browser and test is not shown getting executed in that brower.
I also tried chrome-headless, still no test executes.
Any help !!

Answer (score 0):

In your **karma.conf.js**, change **autoWatch: false** to **autoWatch: true**, then run **ng test** again. Or you could hit the DEBUG button. Hope it helps.